# How do I add a new username and password to a database list in Python?

Tags: python, database, authentication, addition

I am new to Python and I have made this code below. It's just a simple login code that allows you to register or login.

Now I am able to login. As you can see I put the usernames and passwords in the variable `database`.

In the function `register()` I am trying to add the `newusername` and `newpassword` to the `database` list in the form of (username, password) so the `login()` function sees it.

```
import time
import sys
import getpass

database = [
    ("Test1", "123"),
    ("Test2", "000")
    ]


def login():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Welcome. Please login.")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
        time.sleep(1)
        if (username, password) in database:
            print("Welcome, " + username)
            main()
        else:
            print("User not found. Try again.")

def logout():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Logout?")
    lgout = input(">>")
    if lgout == ("yes") or lgout == ("Yes") or lgout == ("YES"):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Logout successful")
        main2()
    elif lgout == ("no") or lgout == ("No") or lgout == ("NO"):
        print("Logout unsuccessful")
        main()
    else:
        print("Command not valid")



def main():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Current commands: Logout")
    while True:
        command = input(">>")
        if command == ("Logout"):
            logout()
        else:
            print("Command not valid")

def main2():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello, would you like to login, register or exit?")
    while True:
        command2 = input(">>")
        if command2 == ("Login") or command2 == ("login") or command2 == ("LOGIN"):
            login()
        elif command2 == ("Register") or command2 == ("register") or command2 ==      ("REGISTER"):
            register()
        elif command2 == ("Exit") or command2 == ("exit") or command2 == ("EXIT"):
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("Command not valid")

def register():
    print("Register your information below")
    newusername = input("Username: ")
    newpassword = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

    print("Success! Please login!")
    login()


main2()
```

Sadly `database["newusername"] = newpassword` does not work since it's not a dictionary.

Comment: You may want to consider actually using dictionaries, as tuples can get pretty insane pretty quickly. `database = {'user1': {'password':'abc123'}, 'user2': {'password':'xyz321'}}` is my suggested database format. This way, if you want to check passwords you just go `if password == database['username']['password']: main()`  if you want to add new users you just take your register()  and make it `database[newusername] = {'password':newpassword}`

Comment: Hey use sessions to improve the login. Second use django or some other framework. You will get used to them pretty soon.

Comment: I followed what TehTris said and now it's much better because I've noticed with tuples you cannot remove elements from it so it makes it very harder later when I try to add a remove user function. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "database" you have here is a list of tuples.

To append something to the end of a list, use .append(). To construct a tuple, use parentheses containing values separated by commas. Putting those two together:

```
database.append( (newusername, newpassword) )
```

Comment: Never knew that the database was a list of tuples. So far I thought it was a dictionary. Anyway it works now thank you so much. You're the best.